# If Kotlin collections are all interfaces, how come they can be instantiated like a class?

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist, collections, interface

I understand that that Kotlin collections map to the Java collections classes in some way, but when I look at the docs and I see that all Kotlin collections are interfaces meant to allow for the option of immutability, I don't see how I can syntactically instantiate these interfaces.

Comment: You can instantiate one of those classes that implement the interfaces, which is what methods like `setOf`, `mapOf` and `listOf` (which you should be using) do.

Comment: In JVM `listOf()` returns the instance returned from `Array.asList()`, `mutableListOf()` returns instance of `ArrayList()`, etc. In Kotlin/Native or Kotlin/JS implementations are their own, you can check the sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all Kotlin collections are interfaces meant to allow for the option of immutability

Actually, not. There are mutable collections too ([1](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-collection/#inheritors), [2](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/#inheritors)).

> I don't see how I can syntactically instantiate these interfaces

As any other interface - by instantiating a class, implementing that interface:

For your convenience, there are several functions in stdlib for this.

Instantiate immutable collections:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-of-not-null.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-set.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-map.html

Instantiate mutable collections:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-map-of.html

Instantiate mutable collections with specific implementation:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-set-of.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-map-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-map-of.html

Instantiate mutable collections with JS-target specific implementation:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/string-set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-string-set-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/string-map-of.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-string-map-of.html